# Different binaries for different localizations for iOS app

Tags: ios, localization

Does anyone know if it is possible to submit different binaries for different localizations in iTunes Connect? The reason I want to do this, is that I have an app with localized speech. Putting the sound files for all languages into the app would considerably grow the binary size, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot submit different binaries for different localizations. You have to provide one binary and bundle all your localized resources in the usual localization folders. But you could provide different *apps* (i.e. with different bundle identifier).

Comment: I was afraid, that would be the answer. Kind of weird though, I would assume, many apps with localized speech would share this problem.

Comment: Well, the only real size limit I know of is the 20MB (IIRC) limit for over-the-air (non-WiFi) install. Apart from that, I don't see a problem with shipping big apps. TomTom is about 700MB last time I looked.

Comment: Could you host the sound files yourself, and have an option in settings to download the other localisations?

Comment: Yes, but in this case you cannot use the usual Apple localization as you cannot store them in the usual directories (your app directory is read-only on iOS). You'd have to download them e.g. into your sandbox Library directory and decide which files to load on your own.

Comment: Sure there is no size limit, but the size for each language is around 25MB. So I don't want to bloat the app size with data, that is only useful for one region.

Comment: Cross-referencing the [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8502841/328948). It says that you could. Is the reason you cannot do so a technical one?

Comment: They're saying that they provided several _apps_ (with different _bundle identifier_). They merely created them out of the same _project_. You could also create different projects and share the source between them, but that would be more fragile, IMHO.