# About Same App, but different binary for different App Stores

Tags: localization, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a new App to launch in the near future. The App is going to have different versions for different Territory's App Store, in sense of UI language and part of App content.

My question is whether I can create different Apps (different bundle IDs and different App's iTunes' Application Name) but with the same App bundle name.

I am doing this because If I include all the UI images for all the languages in one binary and control the language change with code, the App size will be over 20 MG, which I don't want. So, I am deciding to create, compile and submit different binaries separately, at the same time, setting their available App store through "Rights and Pricing" and select certain countries for each version.
I will ensure that two versions of my app won't appear in the same App store to confuse users.

Is this possible? Has anyone done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I built an app with localised content that for the same reasons as you had a European version (localised for French, German, Spanish), a Japanese version a "Rest of the World" version (English only).

We created a targets per version, each one having its own plist with a different bundle id, and for the iTunes application name we used XYZ EU, XYZ Japan, and XYZ (for the English version). The EU version was available in the Spanish, French, German and South American stores, the Japanese in the Japanese store, and the ROW version in all the rest. So this sounds pretty much the same as your set up.

To answer your question, we used the same bundle display name for all 3 targets, without any problem.

You should just create multiple targets for the same project.

[image],

You'll need to create a plist for each target and set the correct bundle name in there, but apart from that they all use the same code. You set the plist name in the build settings for your target.

[image]

When you create a new target, Xcode will create a new scheme for your target, so just switch between schemes to build the appropriate target.

Comment: Thanks Ashley for your prompt answer. Now, I know it can be done. Technically, could you share a bit how you guys handle this in Xcode, so that the code can be easily maintained? Create a workspace, or just new targets for a single project? Thanks.

Comment: I came across this same question when I'm thinking of doing the same thing. Mind if you share the reasons why you took this approach rather than just use one binary and then localizing based on iOS language settings?

Comment: [This answer says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7737150/328948) you can't; that is, you're not allowed to do so by Apple. Can you clarify this?

Comment: The app we were building had a lot of localised images bundled with the app. The client had a requirement that the app be installable over a cellular connection, so to keep it under the 20MB limit we needed to ship multiple versions.

Comment: DarkDust's answer is the same as mine - each target had a different different bundle id (so is in effect a different app).

Comment: Thanks, it's all clear now; the catch is I would have to ship them under separate bundle ids. Were there any significant drawbacks to that (technical, marketing-wise) in your experience?

Yes, I'm also looking to keep the binary under 50 MB (currently the wifi limit).